# Can I pass an array to a React Native ScrollView?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to create a scrollable view using React Native's ScrollView with code below

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, ScrollView, Text, StyleSheet, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    scrollView: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    item: {
        height: '20%',
        width: '100%',
    },
});

const data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    const datum = (
        <View style={styles.item}>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{i.toString()}</Text>
        </View>
    );
    data.push(datum);
}

const App = () => (
    <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
        {data}
    </ScrollView>
);
export default App;
```

Snack URL: https://snack.expo.io/rp6!W!HZm

When I run this code in Snack, seems like I cannot scroll down to the second page. I've checked the official documentation of ScrollView and it is passing ReactElement individually into the view.

RN official doc: https://reactnative.dev/docs/using-a-scrollview

Does this mean I cannot pass an array of elements as the children of a ScrollView? Is there anything I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This should do exactly what you're asking for!

The main thing happening here is the data mapping in the line

```
 {data.map((item, index) => {
                return (<View/>)
     }}
```

where you are defining what is inside the scrollview... also your styling was a tad off so I touched it up.

Hope this helps!

```
 import React from 'react';
 import { ScrollView, Text, StyleSheet, View, Dimensions, SafeAreaView, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

 const { height } = Dimensions.get('screen');

 function App() {
    const data = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        data.push('arbitrary datam #' + (i + 1));
    }

     return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
                {data.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <View key={index} style={styles.item}>
                            <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{item}</Text>
                        </View>
                    );
                })}
            </ScrollView>
        </SafeAreaView>
     );
 }

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    scrollView: {
        height: height,
    },
    item: {
        height: height * 0.2,
        width: '100%',
     },
 });
 export default App;
```

Answer (score -1):

Use flat list:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import{AsyncStorage, View, ScrollView, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import {Text, List} from 'native-base';

class Notes extends Component {

  constructor(props) {

    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: []
    }

  }


  render () {

    return (
        <ScrollView>
        <View style={{margin: 5, marginTop: 5}}>     
        <List>
            <FlatList
                data={this.state.data}
                renderItem={({item, index}) =>
                <View style={styles.item}>
                  <Text style={{ fontSize: 30 }}>{item.toString()}</Text>
                </View>       
                }
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
            />
        </List>

        </View> 
        </ScrollView>
    )
  }




}

export default Notes;
```

Comment: I just want to use a simple ScrollView as they will not be a lot of items in it. Btw, is it a thing to put FlatList inside of a ScrollView? Why don't you just directly use FlatList?

Comment: you can just use flatList, the example i gave has more items inside the scroll view i  removed them

Comment: @AhmadAbouSaleh Telling someone a solution to a different question isn't particularly beneficial without providing context...


ScrollViews can have benefits over FlatLists in certain situations such as when you need to maintain component state 

ScrollViews also load all content at once, which can be nice if you don't have tons of items... then you would probably want a flatlist

See answer below for how to use ScrollView as requested to map an array of data to Views inside a scrollView